# Using iterator to initialize string, get "transposed pointer range" exception

Tags: c++, assertion

Maybe a noob question but why these two lines:

```
vector<char> v{"h","i"};
string s1(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
```

won't compile?
It says:

> "debug assertion failed, exception:transposed pointer range".

Comment: The `{"hi","i"}` will be seen as `{char const* begin, char const* end}` due to pointer decay, but since the two strings are unrelated it is **undefined behavior** as to what happens — which means anything can happen, it may even appear to work as expected (if you are particularly unlucky).

Comment: @Eljay turn this into answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debug assetions happen in **run-time**, not compile time.
In any case, you should change:

```
vector<char> v{"h","i"};
```

to:

```
vector<char> v{ 'h','i' };
```

[`char` literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) should be enclosed with `'`, not `"`.
This way your code should compile and run properly.

See also [@Eljay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531788/using-iterator-to-initialize-string-get-transposed-pointer-range-exception/72531885#comment128127160_72531788) above for more info how the compiler actually interpreted your current code.

**Side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std` - see here [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thanks! Btw I'm aware of the problem of using namespace std, but is there a convienient way to avoid it? Adding std:: everywhere, or write a lot of using std:: *** feels a bit time comsuming, especially when I'm doing excercises of C++ primer, where I need to write a lot of things belong to std.

Comment: @yemeth despite the inconveniency, it's advised to avoid it. The link I posted contains good reasons. It's up yo you of course, but keep in mind if you'll use it a lot you might find it hard to break the [bad] habbit.

Comment: @
wohlstad
done. Thanks again